# JavaScript: Recursive function with Promise, resolve returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I have a recursive function which is returning promise, there is some conditions which on fulfillment the resolve will fire. But the resolve always returns undefined.

Here is the code:

```
var children = [];
var temp = [];
function getRelationsOfRep(repId) {
    var index;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        return RepRelation.findOne({_id: repId}).then(function (repData) {
            if (<condition>) {
                temp = temp.concat(repData.children);
                temp.forEach(function (childId) {
                    return getRelationsOfRep(childId);
                });
            } else {
                // else
            }
            if (<another condition>) {
                return resolve(children);
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {
            return reject(error);
        })
    })
}

function updateRepData(id){
    children = [];
    temp = [];
    getRelationsOfRep(id).then(function (branchesData) {
        console.log('branchesData:: ', branchesData); // it prints undefined
    })
}
```

I'm trying to get all children of a Representative and the children of its children (if any)  and return them all.

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `temp.forEach(function (childId) {
                    return getRelationsOfAgent(childId);
                });` That return value will be ignored. Did you want a `Promise.all`?

Comment: The wrapping in a `new Promise()` seems unnecessary as `RepRelation.findOne()` already looks like a promise itself.

Comment: ahh, now there is recursion - yes, first comment is the key to your "issue"

Comment: not related to the question  use mongodb graphlookup for children search instead in the code. its alot more afficent.

Comment: Since you have made `temp` and `children` outside of the function makes them work as if they were global. ie. only one of them in existence. Moving them to the first line of your function makes them at least local to the current call so that a second deep recursion does not ruin the state of the first. `forEach` seems off since that is just for effect and the returned Promise is never used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making things slightly complicated. I think what you want to achieve is to use promise to return a result from a recursive function.
Here's a cleaner version

A cleaner solution -

```
getRelationsOfRep(repId) {
    return new Promise( function(resolve,reject) {
          recursiveFunctionCall(repId);
          function recursiveFunctionCall(repId) {
             //your recursive function logic
             recursiveFunctionCall(childId);
             if(...) //edge case condition
               resolve('your-answer');
             else 
               reject('your-error')
          }
    });
```

This way, you'll just be using one promise and returning when your recursive function resolves.

Answer (score 3):

Use Promise.all() to capture all the promises in Loop.

Instead of:

```
temp.forEach(function (childId) {
    return getRelationsOfRep(childId);
});
```

Try:

```
var promisesArray = [];
temp.forEach(function (childId) {
    promisesArray.push(getRelationsOfRep(childId));
});
return Promise.all(promisesArray);
```

Using something like this, you will be able to get nested response for the recursive calls.

P.S. Not tested, modify according to the logic you want.

Comment: Still I get undefined, and also value of promisesArray is undefined.